# Replace all letters of a string minus the first and the last in Java

Tags: java, android, regex, string

I have a string, for example this one:

```
stackoverflow
```

And I would like to get the following output in Java (Android):

```
s***********w
```

So we keep the first and the last letters but the other ones are replaced by this sign "*". I want the length of the string to be the same from the input to the output.

Here is the code of the function I have now.

```
String transform_username(String username)
{
    // Get the length of the username
    int username_length = username.length();

    String first_letter = username.substring(0, 1);
    String last_letter = username.substring(username_length - 1);

    String new_string = "";

    return new_string;
}
```

I am able to get the first and the last letter, but I don't really know how to put the "*" in the middle of the word. I know I could loop over it, but it's obviously not a good solution.

Comment: You shouldn't care now about a "bad" solution. Since this task is not complicated you should implement your solution to see how it works. After that you can find advanced/better ways in solving that task.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In one line regex you can do:

```
String str = "stackoverflow";
String repl = str.replaceAll("\\B\\w\\B", "*");
//=> s***********w
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iS2jM3/1)

`\B` is zero-width assertion that matches positions where `\b` doesn't match. That means it matches every letter except first and last.

Answer (score 2):

```
char[] charArr = username.toCharArray();
for (int i=1;i<charArr.length - 1;i++) {
  charArr[i] = 'x';

}
username = new String(charArr);
```

Answer (score 2):

If the string also can contain punctuation try:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?!^).(?!$)","*");
```

The [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) assure to not being at start or end ([regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/jD2qE8/1)).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
String ast = "*";
String new_string = first_letter + StringUtils.repeat(ast, username_length-2) + last_letter;
```

Comment: I believe you mean `StringUtils.repeat(ast, username_length-2)` instead of `ast.repeat(username_length-2)`.

Comment: Well, `StringUtils` is a third party library. Not the best solution though.

Answer (score 0):

Get first and last letter in two string variables and '*' in a string var. and loop from 1 to length-2 and append * in a variable . Then finally append all three.